# Changing/Reading the content of a specified class using BeautifulSoup (BS4)

Tags: python, html, class, beautifulsoup

I want to change the content 'Hey', in `<p class = "test-message-one"> Hey </p>` below:

HTML:

```html
<section id="about" class="about-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>About Section</h1>

                <p class = "test-message-one"> Hey </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is my Python code using the BS4 library:

```
#Manipulating HTML

site_html = open(r"C:\Users\rbaden\desktop\KPI_Site\index.html")


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup =BeautifulSoup(site_html)
#print(soup.prettify())

check_test_content = soup.findAll('tr', { "class" : "test-message-one" })

print(check_test_content)
```

This is the output:

```
[]
```

Why am I just receiving `[]` without any contents?

Is it bad practice to search your HTML via class?

How do I read and change the contents of a specified class?

Comment: Where do you see a `<tr>` element in your HTML sample?

Comment: Even if I take out out

check_test_content = soup.findAll( "test-message-one" )

print(check_test_content)

gives same result

Comment: There is no `<test-message-one>` element in your code either. You don't *have* to give a tag name (the first positional argument) there though.

Comment: edited the code - same result - please see above

Comment: Please don't do that, that invalidates everything we are doing to help you.

Comment: I will undo it - sorry

Comment: no need to, already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the *wrong tag*. You are searching for a `<tr class="test-message-one">` element; the tag name counts too!

Search for the correct tag name or omit the name altogether:

```
check_test_content = soup.findAll('p', {"class": "test-message-one"})
```

or if you omit the name, make sure to *name* the second argument, it is called `attrs`:

```
check_test_content = soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "test-message-one"})
```

Note that the `Element.findAll()` name is *deprecated*; use the new PEP-8 compliant version instead; you can also use the `class_` keyword argument here instead of passing in a dictionary:

```
check_test_content = soup.find_all(class_='test-message-one')
```

The first positional argument is always the tag name, keyword arguments or a dictionary are required to search for attributes like the `class` attribute (but because `class` is a reserved keyword you need to spell it with an extra underscore, so `class_='...'`).

See [*Searching the tree*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) in the documentation.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = '''\
... <section id="about" class="about-section">
...     <div class="container">
...         <div class="row">
...             <div class="col-lg-12">
...                 <h1>About Section</h1>
... 
...                 <p class = "test-message-one"> Hey </p>
... 
...             </div>
...         </div>
...     </div>
... </section>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> soup.find_all(class_='test-message-one')
[<p class="test-message-one"> Hey </p>]
>>> soup.findAll('p', {"class": "test-message-one"})
[<p class="test-message-one"> Hey </p>]
>>> soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "test-message-one"})
[<p class="test-message-one"> Hey </p>]
```

Comment: With 

check_test_content = soup.findAll({"class": "test-message-one"})

print(check_test_content)

I still get [] as the output.

Comment: Its not the whole document - but yes that is a direct copy paste.

Comment: @RubenBaden: ah, in that case you need to explicitly name the dictionary as `attrs`. Corrected.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am new to python and BS4 - can you explain what you mean by: explicitly name the dictionary as attr?

Comment: @RubenBaden: I pass it in as `attr={..}` rather than as a positional argument, which requires that you also pass in a name.

Comment: @RubenBaden: It could be that your HTML is somewhat broken *outside* of this section. Could you try with `BeautifulSoup(site_html, 'html.parser')` if you LXML installed?

Comment: I don't have LXML - but I can install it and try again with the parser.

Comment: I appreciate the help - but I have to go now - will try this first thing in the morning! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I came in and ran the code again first thing this morning - I didn't change anything and it worked. The only thing differently I did was start up a new session of command prompt.?

Comment: So thank you so much! It returned [<p class="test-message-one"> Hey </p>]

But how do I change the contents 'Hey' with a string I have stored in python?

Comment: @RubenBaden: the most likely explanation is that your `soup` did not contain what you thought it had at the time then. :-)